# Что за кодировка?

Tags: php, кодировка, iconv

```
&#1069;&#1082;&#1086;&#1085;&#1086;&#1084;-&#1089;&#1091;&#1087;&#1077;&#1088;
```

В какой кодировке эта строка? и как ее перевести в читаемый текст?

Как можно детектировать кодировку строк?

Comment: cp1251 вроде как

Comment: Это не может быть cp1251, в ней больше 8-ми бит. Скорее всего, utf-8, записанный в десятеричной системе. Первых три буквы 'Эко', если я прав.

Comment: .....`cp936`....  где вы её взяли лучше скажите ....... тут написано `Эконом-супер`, просто к сведению)

Comment: utf-8 Эконом-супер

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это кириллические символы Unicode, кодированный в виде HTML-сущностей. Вы можете получить исходный текст, воспользовавшись декодированием при помощи функции `html_entity_decode()`

```
<?php
$str = '&#1069;&#1082;&#1086;&#1085;&#1086;&#1084;-&#1089;&#1091;&#1087;&#1077;&#1088;';
echo html_entity_decode($str);
```

Comment: По-моему это не UTF-8 кодированный в HTML-сущности

Comment: Это HTML-представление символов UNICODE для кирилицы, декодировать их все-равно придется в UTF-8. http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/cyrchart.html